# Accessing multiple versions of web app, depending on user preference?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, versioning

I haven't gotten into proper versioning (like Git) yet, so I want to do some things myself this first time.

Is it possible, depending on a user's preference (`php + mysql`), to assign a different root path (version) in my `.htaccess` file?

What would be the easiest and most efficiënt way for achieving this? (e.g. no duplicate resources)

Comment: One very popular way of doing this would be having subdomains (`xyz.myapp.com`) or simply subdirectories? `www.myapp.com/152/`

Comment: It is definitely possible but I suggest providing some more details on user preference bit. `.htaccess` cannot query your database so preference should in theory be provided in URL itself like `/v1/site` vs `/v1/site`. Is that something that you're okay with?

Comment: I think you will manage something really harder than simple versionning systems like subversion. Why loosing time in managing a complex stuff instead of using the right tools?

Comment: @regilero Fully agree with you, but I was wondering if there's an easy manual setup just for now.

Comment: I guess a public subdirectory is the easiest and most logical solution. My goal was to show the same url (no version directory) to every user.